# How to plot a scatter plot using a pandas dataframe where the x-axis values are n minus 1 columns and the last column is the dependent variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe (df), let's say it has 12 columns. I need to plot scatterplots of 11 of those columns (my independent variables) against a single column (my dependent variable). In other words, if my column names are 'x1','x2','x3',...'x11', and 'y12' I want to create a 3 by 4 array of scatterplots; all scatterplots will share the same y-axis values 'y12', and each scatterplot will have a different dependent variable ('x1' for the first one, 'x2' for the second scatterplot, and so forth).

I am working with the pandas and matplotlib.pyplot libraries and I need help troubleshooting the following script:

```py
    def plot_df_scatter_columns(x):
    row = [0,1,2]
    column = [0,1,2,3]
    for z in x:
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,4, figsize = (12, 8))

        for i,j in row, column:
            axes[i, j].scatter(df[x], df['y12'])
            axes[i, j].set_title(df.columns[x]+'vs. y12')
    return plt
    plot_df_scatter_columns(df)
```

I expect to see a 3 by 4 array of scatterplots with the same dependent variable ('y12' in the y-axis) and each scatterplot having a unique independent variable (x-axis value). Also, each scatterplot will have a unique title that corresponds to the column that was used as the independent variable (x-axis) from my dataframe.

However, I get a 3 by 4 array of empty plots with no titles.

Error that pops up while working in jupyter notebook:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: You might want to think about what you expect `for i,j in row, column:` to do. It looks like you rather mean `for i in row:` `for j in column:`. Also the use of `x` inside the loop doesn't makes sense. Rather you might use `z` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should move the declaration of `fig, axes` outside the loop so you don't create a new figure for each column.

Also, looping over `for i,j in row, column:` does not work and would create another loop within your loop over the columns, which you don't want.

So rather than specifying rows and columns, just calculate what i and j should be in the `for z in df` loop. Your usage of x as the dataframe and then x as index of the `df` makes no sense. In your function you never even specified `df`, you just don't get an error because the function uses the `df` from the outside scope, which isn't really good practice.

Also, returning `plt` is not really the way to do it, as that stands for the pyplot module. You can just call `plt.show()` in your function, as you don't seem to be assigning your function to anything, there's no need for a return value.

So, altogether a code that works is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# make sample dataframe
dicts = {}
keys = range(12)
for i in keys:
        dicts["x%s"%i] = list(np.random.randint(40, size=20))
dicts["y12"] = list(range(1,21))
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(dicts)

# function to plot your dataframe
def plot_df_scatter_columns(df):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,4, figsize = (12, 8))

    # initialize i and j
    i=0
    j=0

    # loop over df.iloc[:, :-1] instead of df
    # to leave out last column in loop
    for z in df.iloc[:, :-1]:
        axes[i, j].scatter(df[z], df['y12'])
        axes[i, j].set_title(z + 'vs. y12')
        # calculate i and j on the fly during loop over df
        j += 1
        if j > 3:
            j=0
            i += 1

    plt.show()

plot_df_scatter_columns(df_sample)
```

Comment: done! Sorry, new to StackOverflow. Thanks again for your help.